# Java Servlets and ImageIO error

Tags: servlets, thread-safety, javax.imageio, dicom, dcm4che

i'm trying to write a WebApplication which views some DICOM files. My idea was to convert the DICOM files to JPEG on the fly by calling my servlet.
I use dcm4che 2.0.27 to convert the files.

The servlet is called like

```
<img src="pathToServlet/PathToDICOMFile">.
```

The Problem: When i have many  tags (of course addressing different DICOM files) sometimes i get an exception of type java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Here is the method, my servlet is calling:

```
void convertFile(String path, OutputStream to) throws IOException {
    File myDicomFile = new File(path);

    BufferedImage myJpegImage = null;
    ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");

    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();

    DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();

    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(myDicomFile);
    reader.setInput(iis, false);
    myJpegImage = reader.read(0, param);
    iis.close();
    ImageIO.write(myJpegImage, "JPEG", to);

    to.close();

}
```

"path" is the absolute path to the dicom file and "out" is just response.getOutputStream().

The exception can be thrown at 3 places:

1. ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
2. myJpegImage = reader.read(0, param);
3. ImageIO.write(myJpegImage, "JPEG", to);

Here is a stack trace where it was thrown when calling ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM"):

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:835)
at javax.imageio.spi.PartialOrderIterator.<init>(PartiallyOrderedSet.java:177)
at javax.imageio.spi.PartiallyOrderedSet.iterator(PartiallyOrderedSet.java:85)
at javax.imageio.spi.SubRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:759)
at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:451)
at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:507)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName(ImageIO.java:708)
at example.project.dicomtest.myDicomConverter.ConvertHelper.convertFile(ConvertHelper.java:32)
at example.project.dicomtest.myDicomConverter.GetImage.doGet(GetImage.java:40)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEnginateValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Is it because ImageIO is not thread safe? What can i do to solve this issue?
Thank you very much for any help and best regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two lines:

```
ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
```

Only need to be done once, when your application loads or your servlet is initialized. In particular, the first line `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` does mutate shared data used by the ImageIO class internally. This is likely the cause of your concurrent modification exceptions. Consider moving those two lines to either a servlet filter, or to the `init(ServletConfig)` method of your servlet.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

use synchronized methods to prevent concurrent modification can be of help.  read this question

stackoverflow.com/questions/9884148/use-of-synchronized-method-in-affable-bean-shopping-cart